# Find degree of extension $Q$($\sqrt{1+\sqrt{-3}}$ + $\sqrt{1-\sqrt{-3}}$) over $Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I tried solving this textbook problem.Any hint how to simplify or find the degree of extension in this case ?I guess maximum degree can be 4.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you find a bound on the degree?  Can you find a polynomial that vanishes on $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{-3}}-\sqrt{1-\sqrt{-3}}$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr i guess maximum degree can be 4(i.e bound)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let $x=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{-3}}+\sqrt{1-\sqrt{-3}}$.  Then, observe that
$$
x^2=1+\sqrt{-3}+2\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{-3})(1-\sqrt{-3})}+1-\sqrt{-3}=2+2\sqrt{1-(-3)}=6.
$$
Therefore, this satisfies $x^2-6=0$.

What do you think now?  Are there any rationals that satisfy $x^2=6$?

Comment: it is irreducible and hence degree is 2 thus degree of extension is 2 .

Comment: For complex numbers $a$ and $b$, the equality $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b}$ is tricky: what does it produce when $a=b = -1$?

Comment: @Catalin Of course, some assumptions need to be made here.  At minimum, the same branch of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ should be used for both square roots in the original expression.  In particular, if one avoids the branch cut along the negative real axis and then observes that the arguments are conjugates of each other, this issue will not arise.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If we let $\alpha=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{-3}}+\sqrt{1-\sqrt{-3}}$ then what is $\alpha^2$?

Comment: i got answer is 2 right !

Comment: You can show that $\alpha^2=6$. From there it is easy.